# Binary Classification with almost no positives

Tags: machine-learning, classification, sampling

I have a dataset with 121 features and 7176 data points. Only 11 of these are positive, the rest is negative. If I want to train a SVM on this data set, what would be the best strategy to do this? Does this even make sense?

For now I decided to 5-fold cross validation with stratified sampling. Would this approach be reasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *positive* class prior of $0.0015$, which is way to low to train a classifier from. You need at least an excess of $100$ positive cases, your most rare class. You will be able to start with a few (most) discriminative features.

Next, a support vector machine ***is not a suited classifier*** for such a skewed prior distribution. A recommended approach is to train for example a random forest classifier, a decision tree (C4.5 or CART) and discriminant-analysis/logistic-regression. Use a balanced training set and correct the posterior probabilities post hoc, see the approach for this [correcting for a skewed prior after training](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/476911/how-are-artificially-balanced-datasets-corrected-for/476948#476948).

**After note**

The set of $100$ required positive cases is chosen based on experience. With $121$ different feature values, this number is at an absolute minimum. A classifier like C4.5 does feature selection while building the decision tree (starting with each individual feature variable).

More theoretical work can begin with the paper by *E.B. Baum, D. Haussler, What size net gives valid generalization? Neural Computation, Vol. 1, No. 1, March 1989*. Having computed with the guidelines from their Corollary 9, to ensure an error rate of $0.015$, $121$ feature variables, you need $125$ training cases. I assumed *one* parameter/weight per feature variable (one hidden node - the simplest neural network classifier).

Beware that their results are based on the nonparametric VC-dimension. In practice, their bounds are below what is needed to fit well-generalizing decision boundaries.
Using more model parameters than training cases, that is discouraged.

Comment: Where is an excess of 100 positive cases recommended? Can you provide some literature? Your answer is very valuable, thanks. I actually have the same problem with a OneClass SVM (see my other question on cross validated). I would appreciate it very much, if you could have a look at my other question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/478565/oneclass-svm-does-not-detect-a-single-outlier

Comment: I have added some literature. Much later research has been built on the results by Baum & Haussler (1989).