# What is a reasonable number of splits (maximum) for a ensemble classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, ensemble-learning, adaboost

I am trying to use an ensemble classifier (honing in on Matlab fitcensemble).  I've also explored using a single decision tree as well as tree bagging (Matlab fitctree, TreeBagger)

Simple binary (A/B) classification.   My training dataset is imbalanced (~5% B).  Currently playing with 24 features, but that could change.  But I have ~1.7 million of rows. I could have 10x that number of rows if I wanted.

I am trying to decide on parameters related to tree size.  "Min Leaf Size" and "Max Number of Splits".  I'm exploring the ('OptimizeHyperparameters','all') option which is exploring a variety of settings, but it is showing what I already figured out, which is that having a large number of splits gives better performance.  (It seems to be honing in on the AdaBoostM1 method.)

When my max number of splits is ~1/2 my number of rows I am getting
Sensitivity (for B):  98% (train), 86% (test)
Specificity (for A): 99% (train), 93% (test)

Really I want better than 86% Sensitivity, however my gut tells me having N splits be ~1/2 rows is too high.

The asker in this question states they set their maximum number of splits to 1/16th the number of rows in their dataset:

[Balance classifier performance (boosting ensemble)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/482108/balance-classifier-performance-boosting-ensemble)

That sounds like they are calling upon a rule of thumb (which I value), but its just one example.  Can anyone provide guidance/reference for how many splits is reasonable?  Beyond simply trying many options and see what works?